# VBA: Copy & Paste Between Worksheets with a Function

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this function in order to copy and paste values between two worksheets. The function works great as a sub, but I am trying to further automate my process by accepting a str argument. The Function accepts my str argument; however, instead of pasting the correct values it throws a #VALUE! exception. Any idea or help is greatly appreciated!!!
Here's my code so far:

```
Function slam2(str)
Windows("Data Sheet.xlsx").Activate
Dim SCol As Integer
With Range("A2:ZZ2")

    Set PValue = .Find(What:=str, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
If Not PValue Is Nothing Then
    Cell_Split_R = Split(PValue.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
    Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
    SRow = Cell_Split_C(0)
    SCol = Cell_Split_C(1)
    
End If
End With
Range(Cells(15, SCol).Address, Cells(26, SCol).Address).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Function

Comment: Functions called from a worksheet have limitations: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=Change%20another%20cell%27s%20value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub ExampleSub()
    'Sub to initiate function
    Call slam2(InputBox("Type Value to Find", "Copy/Paste", ""))
End Sub
Sub slam2(str)
    
    Dim sCol As Long
    Dim sRow As Long
    Dim Pvalue As Range
    
    ' >>> Your workbook(s)
    Dim WB1 As Workbook
    Set WB1 = Workbooks("Trial Space.xlsm")
    
    With WB1.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("A2:AZ2")
        
        Set Pvalue = .Find(What:=str, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
            
        If Not Pvalue Is Nothing Then
            sRow = Pvalue.Row
            sCol = Pvalue.Column
        End If
        
    End With
    
    
    WB1.Worksheets("Pasting Sheet").Range(Cells(15, 1).Address, Cells(26, 1).Address).Value = _
        WB1.Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range(Cells(15, sCol).Address, Cells(26, sCol).Address).Value
    
End Sub
```