# How to avoid value errors in VBA with UDFs

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to call the function written below, but I am getting a #VALUE error that I simply can't figure out. When I call the function in the sub below, I have no problems and I am able to return the values I am looking for. I am just confused and looking for any advice!! Thanks in advance!!!!

```
Function findNum(VehName As String, iqsNum As String) As Double
    Windows("Numbers Sheet.xlsx").Activate 'activates the sheet where we get data
    Dim SCol1 As Integer 'Dimension variables
    Dim SRow As Integer
    With Range("A3:A999") 'selects the range where we are looking

    Set PValue = .find(What:=iqsNum, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'looks for the value
    
    'goes through the sheet and grabs the location of the cell and makes it SRow and SCol
    If Not PValue Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(PValue.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SRow = Cell_Split_C(0)
        SCol = Cell_Split_C(1)
        
    End If
    End With
    
    With Range("A3:ZZ3")

    Set PValue = .find(What:=VehName, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    If Not PValue Is Nothing Then
        Cell_Split_R = Split(PValue.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), "R")
        Cell_Split_C = Split(Cell_Split_R(1), "C")
        SRow1 = Cell_Split_C(0)
        SCol1 = Cell_Split_C(1)
        
    End If
    End With
    Cells(SRow, SCol1).Select 'selects the cell we're looking at
    Cells(3, 30) = Cells(SRow, SCol1)
    findNum = Cells(SRow, SCol1)
End Function
Sub caller() 'using this sub to verify the code in findNum() actually works
    Dim Z As Double
    Z = findNum("BigName", 178)
    Windows("Analysis Sheet.xlsm").Activate
    Cells(3, 31) = Z
End Sub
```

Comment: UDFs shouldn't `.Select` or `.Activate`. [Avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: ^^^ in fact when they are called by a cell formula they CANNOT `.Select` or `.Activate` or they will return `#Value`

Comment: They also cannot set a value to any other cell that is not the one being called. `Cells(3, 30) = Cells(SRow, SCol1)` is not allowed in a UDF that is called from a cell.

Comment: Tim Williams [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73068295/vba-copy-paste-between-worksheets-with-a-function#comment129052985_73068295) the limitations of UDFs.

Comment: Ah, that took me way too long to figure out... It's an `=index(array,match(),match())` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using "=Index(Array, Match(), Match())"

[image: Example of formula]

> =INDEX($C$3:$M$16,MATCH(D19,B3:B16,0),MATCH(D20,C2:M2,0))

[image]